# Error en envio de email para reestablecer contraseña (FORGOTPASSWORD) ASP.NET, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

```
//
    // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            // if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            if( user == null )
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("","El correo es invalido");
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send an email with this link

            string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
             var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);     
             await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }


public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{

    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Credentials:
        var envia = "correo@hotmail.com";
        var user = "correo@hotmail.com";
        var pass = "contraseña";
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential( user, pass );
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = "smtp.live.com",
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Port = 25,
            EnableSsl = true,
            Credentials = credentials
        };
        var mail = new MailMessage(envia, message.Destination);

        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        return client.SendMailAsync(mail);



    }
   }
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> Error en la transacción. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:OutboundSpamException; Failed to process
>   message due to a permanent exception with message WASCL UserAction
>   verdict is not None. Actual verdict is Suspend, ShowTierUpgrade.
>   OutboundSpamException: WASCL UserAction verdict is not None. Actual
>   verdict is Suspend, ShowTierUpgrade.
>   [Hostname=CY4PR05MB3414.namprd05.prod.outlook.com]

Error de código fuente:

> Línea 315:                 await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id,
>   "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking here");

Comment: Hola ViA Alondra, te recomiendo postear tu solución no en la pregunta, sino más bien en una respuesta y seleccionarla como la correcta, así otros que tengan un problema similar sabrán que se pudo solucionar de esa manera. Si tienes dudas de como hacerlo lee [answer]. Saludos :)

Comment: Gracias lo tomare en cuenta :) . Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SOLUCIÓN

**Sólo hice cambio en esta parte del código,** El error que me comenzo a dar fue el siguiente el metodo del FOrgotPassword lo deje como estaba

> El servidor SMTP requiere una conexión segura o el cliente no se
> autenticó. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.5.1 Auth.....

Y la modificación que hice al código fue la siguiente *NOTA: Este método pertenece a la clase de IdentityConfig.cs ahí es donde modifique el método*

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{

    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Credentials:
        var envia = "correo_@hotmail.com";
        var user = "nombreUsuario";
        var pass = "**********";
        //Elimine una linea de código
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = "smtp.live.com",
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Port = 25,
            EnableSsl = true,
             //Aqui hice modificacion, agregando los parametros del correo 
            //que va a enviar el mensaje y la contraseña de ese correo
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(envia, pass)

    };
        var mail = new MailMessage(envia, message.Destination);

        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        return client.SendMailAsync(mail);
    }

}
```

Comment: Bajo los puntos de esta respuesta en la parte izquiera aparece un símbolo de check, éste te servirá para marcarlo como respuesta correcta ;)

Comment: Hola, traté de hacerlo al momento que respondí . :( Pero me dice que dentro de 24 hrs puedo darle palomita a mi respuesta. Gracias por la sugerencia. Saludos :)

Comment: Ah bueno, vale :)

Answer (score 0):

Como todavía no puedo preguntarte, me animaré a tratar de darte una respuesta.

La excepción me parece bastante clara: la cuenta que estás usando se encuentra suspendida, motivo por el cual no puedes realizar el envío de correos con la misma. Procura entrar a la cuenta manualmente y reestablecer la misma.

Por otro lado, a modo de sugerencia, ten el método de envío de correos electrónicos en una clase aparte, tal vez en una EmailHelper, para que puedas referenciar a esa clase desde cualquier método con la referencia correcta.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me mandaba mucho ese error pero despues solo cambie una linea de código y funciono :) . Gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Tu correo está siendo clasificado como Spam.

> OutboundSpamException

Comprueba que estás usando los datos correctos del SMTP de hotmail

```
Hotmail SMTP Server: smtp.live.com
Hotmail SMTP Username: me@hotmail.com o me@live.com
Hotmail SMTP Password: contraseñaUltraSecreta
Hotmail SMTP Port: 587
Hotmail SMTP TLS/SSL Required: yes
```

Si esto no funciona, posiblemente la cuenta que usas requiera una validación previa (una única vez). O el admin del dominio deba quitar tu usuario de la [lista de usuarios bloqueados](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/SecurityCompliance/removing-a-user-domain-or-ip-address-from-a-block-list-after-sending-spam-email).

Comment: Ya pude solucionar el problema, el error estaba en el acomodo de dos lineas de código . Muchas Gracias :) por tu aporte